# Read xml files using Powershell XMLReader without locking the xml file

Tags: xml, powershell, xmlreader

I am looking to read xml files using xmlreader without causing lock on the file. all my operations are read only

```
$reader= system.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlfile)
```

whenever I use $reader.read() I can't seem to get another thread read the same file..
any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file into a string, wrap the string in a StringReader and pass that to the XmlReader.Create method e.g.:

```
$str = Get-Content C:\temp\foo.xml -Raw
$stringReader = new-object system.io.stringreader $str
$xmlReader = [system.xml.xmlreader]::Create($stringReader)
```